# "Fiction is to grown men *what* play is to the child"

Tags: sentence-construction, comparison, parts-of-speech

I'm confused with the quote:

> Fiction is to grown men **what** play is to the child.

What does this structure mean, especially "what"?

Comment: Can you clarify what's confusing? Are the words unfamiliar? Do they appear to have unusual meanings? Is the structure of the sentence itself strange?

Comment: I think the structure of the sentence is unusual. What is the grammatical function of the word "what"?

Comment: Exercise is to the body what reading is to the mind.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a slightly modified version of your sentence:

> Fiction is a joy to grown men.

"A joy to grown men" is the predicative expression in this sentence. Likewise, "what play is to the child" is the predicative expression in your sentence. More specifically, it is a predicative clause (a wh-clause). The word "what" is a relative pronoun in this clause.

Another example, which you may feel more comfortable with, is

> That is what I want.

See also wikipedia content [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause#Wh-clauses).

Comment: Thanks, Laugh. Do you mean "play is also a joy to the child"?

Comment: The original sentence compares (the meaning of) fiction to grown men to (the meaning of) play to the child. I used parentheses because "the meaning of" is not in the sentence; it is *implied*. You can also say that both are a source of joy, and then indeed "play is a joy to the child".

Answer (score 0):

In the structure of your sentence

> Fiction is to grown men **what** play is to the child.
>   *something is to someone* **what** *something-else is to someone-else*

is an **analogy** comparing something for grown men **in terms of** something for children

The analogy is that whatever **play** is to a child

> **entertainment**
>   **educational**
>   **time-consuming**
>   **calming**
>   **exciting**

**fiction** is to grown men in the same way.

The equivalent would be

> Fiction is play for grown men.

if **play** is understood to be **play for children**.
*(not to be confused with* ***child's play*** *which is an idiom meaning* ***very easy*** *)*

Comment: Maybe I'm just seeing things, but I think there might be a bit more to the original wording than you're describing. I see the sentence as saying, "Children engage in _playing_; grown men partake in the [somewhat more refined and mature term] _fiction_." That is: _Children like to get lost in fantasy worlds in their imagination when they play, grown-ups get lost in fantasy worlds when they read_. I guess that's about the same as what you're saying, too, but I wanted to take another stab at it. It's a form of [rhetorical parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_%28rhetoric%29).